# 19.10 studio not able to print after installation

Tags: printing, 19.10

Please help, I've installed studio 19.10 and printer was installed but the Cups server failed and now I've read some commend that said to remove the cups server, what I' ve did and now the printer is gone too. I have a HPdeskjet and I also have via the Sofware the HPLIP installed..???
Now what to do?

Comment: Reinstall CUPS, and whatever else you may have uninstalled.

Comment: What is your exact printer model?

Comment: HPdeskjet J6410

Comment: How to reinstall CUPS? I can' t find it

Comment: Thanks you all, Reinstall Cups has not worked. I have installed studio 19.10 again. First I try to reinstall but that failed. Then I installed studio as a new install and now the printer and all work perfectly.